# Code needs to work for more possibilities

Tags: python

**The Question**

```
is_match:
(str, str) -> bool
```

The first parameter is a puzzle and the second is a view. Return True iff the view could be a view of the given puzzle.

**My Answer**

I came up with this:

```
def is_match(puzzle, view):
    if len(puzzle) != len(view):
        return False
    if len(puzzle) == len(view):
        return True
```

I also found this online:

```
def is_match(given_puzzle, view):
    if len(given_puzzle) != len(view):
        return False
    unique_letters = set(ch for ch in view if ch != '^')
    for (a, b) in zip(given_puzzle, view):
        if a in unique_letters and a != b:
            return False
    return True
```

This issue I am having is that if I input:

```
is_match('blah', 'tr^^')
```

It will return True for both of the given codes. Which must be wrong due to the fact that the characters don't even match only the length of the string does
What could i do to fix this?

Comment: What's a puzzle? For all I know, 'tr^^' _is_ a possible view of 'blah', since you haven't told us any of the puzzle's rules.

Comment: Could you please clarify what this puzzle is? We shouldn't have to go through your previous questions to figure out what you mean.

Comment: this is basically a game of hangman and a puzzle is any word that needs to be solved for example "apple" is the puzzle that needs to be solved, the view which is given will be '^^^^^'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a previous string of questions about this "puzzle" game, I infer that you want something like:

```
def is_match(puzzle,view):
    return all(p == v for p,v in zip(puzzle,view) if v != '^' )
```

*Note that this assumes that `puzzle` and `view` have the same length.

What this does is iterate over puzzle and view at the same time, yielding the next character from each as `p` and `v` (the magic of `zip`).  I check to make sure that `v` is not `'^'` (the placeholder character).  If it isn't a placeholder, I check if it equals `p` (the character from `puzzle`).  If at any time this latter check fails, then the function returns `False`.  Otherwise, it returns `True`.

Comment: where should i place that within the code? in the beginning or at the end

Comment: @JohNDoe -- It's a function that doesn't rely on any globals, so it can go anywhere (just so long as python sees it *before* you try to actually use it).

Comment: @JohNDoe -- No problem.  I just ask that you make sure that you understand it well before you turn it in.  :)

Comment: so i cahnged it to this

def is_match(puzzle, view):
 return all(p == v for p, v in zip (puzzle, view) if v != '^')
 if len(puzzle) != len(view):
  return False
 if len(puzzle) == len(view):
  return True


but the problem is when i enter something like

is_match ('blah', '^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^')

itll return True even though the view has way more characters now

Comment: @JohNDoe -- `return (len(puzzle) == len(view)) and all(...)`.  This checks the length before checking the individual characters..